# DIY Swing Set. Need angle measurements

Tags: measurement, swing

Using common swing brackets for use with 4- 4x4x8 posts and 1- 4x6x10 beam, at what angle do I cut the bottom of the 4x4 posts to sit flush on the ground?

Comment: I did not cut mine, I was using wood trunks for the rustic look, but sank them in holes about a foot deep with concrete to help. But you could do a drawing and use triginometry - all the fun of sines and cosines from school...

Comment: try 45 degree angle

Comment: How much does your yard slope? In other words, nothing is going to sit perfectly flush so I think SolarMike’s suggestion to sink the posts is spot on.

Comment: N.B. putting "asap" in your question body is [considered rude](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/326590/4037594).

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing the design of the brackets this is impossible to answer, but rather than calculate angles using trigonometry, there's an easier way:

Assemble it, and sit it on the ground. Then use an offcut of 4x2 or whatever, laid on the ground next the posts to mark a line parallel to the ground on each one. Then take it apart, cut them, and re-assemble.